# LSTM using word embeddings and TFIDF vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf-idf

I am trying to run LSTM on a dataset that has text attributes and TFIDF vectors. I word embed the text and input to LSTM layer. Next, I concatenate the LSTM output and the TFIDF vectors. However, line 2 in the code below throws the following error:

"ValueError: Layer lstm_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: . Full input: []. All inputs to the layer should be tensors."

The code is given below, where len(term_Index)+1 = 9891, emb_Dim=100, emb_Mat contains floats and has shape [9891,100], and sen_Len=1000:

```
    embed = Embedding(len(term_Index) + 1, emb_Dim, weights=[emb_Mat], 
    input_length=sen_Len, trainable=False)
    lstm = LSTM(60, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1)(embed)
    tfidf_i = Input(shape=(max_terms_art,))
    conc = Concatenate()(lstm, tfidf_i)
    drop = Dropout(0.2)(conc)
    dens = Dense(1)(drop)
    acti = Activation('sigmoid')(dens)

    model = Model([embed, tfidf_i], acti)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit([features_Train, TFIDF_Train], target_Train, epochs = 50, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.20)
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in concatenate, the input should be a list conc = Concatenate()([lstm, tfidf_i])

Comment: I tried adding brackets, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I cannot reproduce your error. After I added the bracket, the code run perfectly. See my code below:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Concatenate, Dropout, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

emb_Mat = tf.random.normal((9891,100)).numpy()
term_Index = tf.random.uniform((9890,)).numpy()
sen_Len=1000
emb_Dim=100
max_terms_art=500

inp = Input(shape=(len(term_Index),))
embed = Embedding(len(term_Index) + 1, emb_Dim, weights=[emb_Mat], input_length=sen_Len, trainable=False)(inp)
lstm = LSTM(60, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1)(embed)
tfidf_i = Input(shape=(max_terms_art,))
conc = Concatenate()([lstm, tfidf_i])
drop = Dropout(0.2)(conc)
dens = Dense(1)(drop)
acti = Activation('sigmoid')(dens)

Model([inp, tfidf_i], acti).summary()
```

Outputs:

```
Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_16 (InputLayer)           [(None, 9890)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_15 (Embedding)        (None, 9890, 100)    989100      input_16[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_8 (LSTM)                   (None, 60)           38640       embedding_15[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_17 (InputLayer)           [(None, 500)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 560)          0           lstm_8[0][0]                     
                                                                 input_17[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 560)          0           concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            561         dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 1)            0           dense_1[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,028,301
Trainable params: 39,201
Non-trainable params: 989,100
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks! I successfully made a model now. But, now I got a new error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (9891,) but got array with shape (1000,),  when running: history = model.fit([features_Train, TFIDF_Train], target_Train, epochs = 50, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.2)

Comment: Your embedding input is incorrect. Make sure your input mismatch what each layer want. From my guess, it seems that your input to the Embedding layer is incorrect. The input to the embedding layer should be a dimension of (batch_size, seq_len). Please recheck if your input implementation is correct :)

Comment: Yeah, the shape was wrong, I already fixed it. Thanks anyways :)